# Input Value Change causes font import

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm working with reactjs and styled-components. 
I got an InputComponent which contains an styled.input.
My parent component contains this Input component, an styled.h1 const and a button component.

My parent render looks like this:

```html
  render() {
    return (
      <Div>
        <GlobalStyle/>
        <H1>Hallo</H1>
        <MyInput value={this.state.value} onChangeValue={this.handleChangeValue} />
        <br/><MyButton msg={this.state.value}/>
      </Div>
    );
  }
```

Maybe you noticed the GlobalStyle component. The GlobalStyle component is from styled-components and provides inheritable styles.
It looks like this:

```html
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle `
  body {
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
  }
`
```

My problem is:
The font is initially working, but when I type something in my input field it re-downloads the font and resets my h1. Live it look like its getting bold & unbold but its just changing fonts.

After a few letters my network debug looks like this:[Network image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wCgB.png)

Thanks for helping me out.

Project https://codesandbox.io/s/github/robertdudaa/reactjstest

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle `
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
  body {
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
  }
`
```

or you can simply import font in index.html in your public folder of project directory:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>`

hope it's help you
Thank-you :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help but both solutions does not work.

Comment: owh..could you please upload your file on [here](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: its super weird, sometime it works, sometime it does not work https://codesandbox.io/s/github/robertdudaa/reactjstest

Comment: i don't find any thing that you applied
here is your [public](https://pasteboard.co/HJ0hMVM.jpg) html
and [here](https://pasteboard.co/HJ0iceN.jpg) is your css

You can add 

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>`

in your index.html file in public folder 
and add
`font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;`
in your css